# Advantage of SessionStorage over Cookie

Tags: javascript, security, html

Q1-> What are the advantage of SessionStorage/LocalStorage over Cookie ?

Q2-> A Value stored by xyz site can be viewed or edited by any other site or the user ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Session Storage and Local Storage allow for a greater capacity (currently 5mb with most browsers), and are not sent back to the server for every HTTP request (HTML, images, JavaScript, CSS, etc) - reducing the amount of traffic between between client and server (saving you $dosh).

2) Local / Session Storage are both restricted to the domain setting/getting the values, so if you use `localStorage.set('key', 'val')` on www.domain1.com, you cannot access that data using `localStorage.get('key')` on www.domain2.com. Bear in mind the restriction also applies to domains and subdomains - i.e. you cannot access www.domain1.com local/session storage from sub.domain1.com either.

**Update** from @josh3736: users, however, have full access to the raw local and session storage. This is how users are currently able to unlock all levels on the web version of Angry Birds: http://wesbos.com/all-levels-html5-angry-birds/ - to reiterate Josh, never trust data at the client tier.

More details here: http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/storage.html

Comment: One thing you did not address: yes, data in local storage can be viewed or edited by the user.  For example, in Chrome, open the Dev Tools and go to the Resources tab.  There you can easily see and edit everything the current domain has in local storage.  (Like anything else on the web, **never trust client data**.)

Comment: josh3736: "never trust client data", cannot be stressed or repeated enough times.

Comment: Is there a way to verify the data integrity on the client side (practical, I suppose one can always store things as a single string and check that against a hash or similar)?

Comment: "never trust client data" is a very bad blanket statement.  At some point you HAVE to trust it, logging into a site usually produces a session key (usually in the form of a cookie) and you have to trust that the client will send that specific key back to you.  This key tells the server side software who is actually requesting data, so that you are not passing around the username/password back and forth over and over again.  I would say that you can expect the data to be in ANY form and that all server side software should verify data conforms to its use, trust is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage of using Session Storage its performance in using it. Especially for large data (100kb,etc). Simple cookies would have to be a part of each request to the server. So you won't get this stored data to the server by simple means, but I can libe with that.